# Render images in datatables in shiny

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

Is there a way to render images in a datatable in shiny ?

If I try adding the  tag

```
paste(<img src="http://test.com/img/', x, '.jpg" height=52></img>', sep='')
```

as part of the column (in which i want to show the image) it just spits out the html tag and not the image.

Comment: have you tried the `escape=FALSE` option?  It works to make links function in a datatable, seems like it may work for an image as well

Comment: awesome that works! Can you add this as an answer so you get credit for it ?

Comment: nice to know it works, I didnt even test it, so you should just answer your own question if you're motivated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @bunk mentioned, escape=FALSE works for embedding the images in a datatable.